# Difference between the weight parameter in xgb.DMatrix and scale_pos_weight in hyper params list?

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost

I am having a little difficulty understanding what's the difference between the `weight` function in `xgb.DMatrix` and the `sum_pos_weight` parameter in the `param` list. I am going through the following [code](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/demo/kaggle-higgs/higgs-train.R) which is using the Higgs data;

---

Due to the data being unbalanced, the author defines a weight parameter:

```
weight <- as.numeric(dtrain[[32]]) * testsize / length(label)

sumwpos <- sum(weight * (label==1.0))
sumwneg <- sum(weight * (label==0.0))
```

However column 32 is already a `weight` variable, so the author is modifying an already defined weight variable?

Then, the modified `weight` variable is being set as the "weight" argument of `xgb.DMatrix`:

```
xgmat <- xgb.DMatrix(data, label = label, weight = weight, missing = -999.0)
```

Additionally, in the param list the author has: `"scale_pos_weight" = sumwneg / sumwpos,`.

so `scale_pos_weight` is a function of `sumneg` which is a function of `weight` which is a function of `a previously defined weight (column 32)`. So I am confused.

1. What does the author do in the following line: `weight <- as.numeric(dtrain[[32]]) * testsize / length(label)`
2. What is the difference in setting the `weight` in `xgb.DMatrix` and again in `sum_pos_weight`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set

`xgmat <- xgb.DMatrix(data, label = label, weight = weight, missing = -999.0)`

`weight` should be a vector corresponding to your data rows

If for example you have the following data:

```
  A B C
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
```

you need to set `weight` as a vector of 2 weights

```
weight <- c(1, 2)
```

So you will have a weight of 1 to the first event and weight of 2 to the 2nd event. You ask your self why is it good? Assume event 1 has happened 1 time and event 2 happened 2 times, you'd like co responsive weights to them specifically mentioning the amount of time that event has occurred.

Here are few more examples for using weights:

1. If you want recent events to have more "value"
2. The amount of confidence you have in a data row. you will set all weights to be between 0 to 1 and the weight will represent how much you sure of that data. for example if weight = 0.88 you gave that row 88% confidence
3. If you have repetitive events. instead of creating more rows, you can set them once and give them a weight as the number they've repeated

`scale_pos_weight` is usually used when you have "imbalanced data". for example, assuming you have a classification problem where you have 5% of the data as 1 and 95% of the data as 0, you would like to give more weight for every **positive** "event". So you can just set scale_pos_weight = 19 (or as the author wrote: `sumneg/sumpos`)

As for the "author" re defining weight. I cannot know without the full code what he did there, but I assume he's doing some sort of normalization to the weights.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! In regards to the first point of creating a vector `weight <- c(1,2)`. It does not actually have anything to do with imbalanced data? (a lot of models I have seen leave this part out of the `xgb.DMatrix()`). If I have a classification problem such as in the titanic, how would I set the weight in this instance or is it not used here? Would I use the number of rows in the data?

Comment: Don't set weights if there's no valid reason to do so.

Comment: Here's a simple example of when to set weights. If you have repetitive events. instead of creating more rows, you can set them once and give them a weight as the number they've repeated.

Comment: Here's another example. The amount of confidence you have in a data row. you will set all weights to be between 0 to 1 and the weight will represent how much you sure of that data. for example if weight = 0.88 you gave that row 88% confidence.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, it has cleared somethings up for me. Regarding the `sumpos / sumneg`. Assuming the classification example you set, why do we want to give **more** weight to a positive event? Suppose I have 5% of patients classified with a disease and 95% healthy. I would like to assign a higher weight when the algorithm correctly classifies a patient  with a disease, so `sum_pos_weight` in this instance would be `sumneg / sumpos` or `5/95` or `0.053`.

Comment: So is it true that now the algorithm will assign a weight of `0.053` to every positively assigned patient? and the patients with the disease (when they are correctly assigned) will have a weight of `0.947`?

Comment: Hell no. You got it all backwards. You try to classify a DISEASED patient so you assign him with class 1. That is your POSITIVE weight. Usually the "positive" events are less frequent in data sets. And that's why we give them HIGHER weight.